# Matching rows of the same dataframe in pandas python

Tags: database, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the rows are coupled (they refer to the same *event*): I've created two key-variables (*myKey_forMatch* and *myKey_toBeMatched*), that should match in order to couple the observations in the dataframe:

[original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnVTZ.png)

My desiderata is to get a dataframe with only one row for each *event*:

[resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhmB.png)

Can anyone give me any hints? (just to avoid any misunderstanding, in the full dataframe the rows to be coupled do not always follow the pattern as in the example shared)

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to solve this, but my personal approach would be to make a new dataframe with two columns, 'myKey_forMatch' and 'data' (which I would rename 'data_match'), and another dataframe with all of the other columns, including the original 'data'. Then I would join the two like this:

firstdf.set_index('myKey_forMatch').join(seconddf.set_index('myKey_toBeMatched'))

Hope this helps

Comment: This has been of great help, thanks! The dataframe that i get contains twice all events though, i.e. row1 matched with row2 and also row2 matched with row1. How can avoid it?

Comment: Have a read through this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

You may want to try different kinds of joins. The default is 'left'... experiment with 'inner'. You could also stick with your current result and play around with a df.drop_duplicates type command.

Comment: I tried to play on the options but didn't get an hint from the reference you passed me. This is due to the fact that the two dfs have the same keys, meaning that choosing left / right / inner you get always the same result. Also dropping duplicates is not successful, since the keys are unique in each column, the rows should be dropped only if they have been matched so far. This is what I can understand so far, but I'm quite a newer to pandas. Can you specify better what's your idea?